# Laravel belongsToMany inserting '0' on pivot table ids in a many to many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have the following schema:

#### An `objects` table

```
    Schema::create('objects', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('object_id');
    });
```

With a relation of:

```
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'objects_tags_pivot', '?', '?');
}
```

#### A `tags` table:

```
    Schema::create('tags', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('tag_id');
    });
```

With a relation of:

```
public function objects() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Object', 'objects_tags_pivot', '?', '?');
}
```

And a pivot between them for the many to many relationship present:

```
    Schema::create('objects_tags_pivot', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('object_tags_id');
        $table->integer('object_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
    });
```

My question is what to insert into the relationship parameters where I currently have question marks? The Laravel 4.2 documentation suggests that the third parameter is `$foreignKey` and the fourth is `$localKey`. This isn't very helpful.

Every attempt at matching `object_id` and `tag_id` up with these parameter, or leaving them blank, has resulted in one or more of the fields on the pivot table being `0`. Not useful at all.

What order should I specify each parameter in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried leaving them null? Laravel will already make foreign and local / other key assumptions based on the table name of the relation. For example, since the `objects` table model name is `Object` it will guess that the foreign key is named `object_id`. Also, since the `tags` model name is `Tag`, it will guess `tag_id` for the local / other key in a relationship.

If you want to fill them out manually, you need to insert the column names that indicate how the relationship is linked. For example:

```
public function tags()
{
     $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'objects_tag_pivot', 'object_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

Comment: Yep, this does work. Accepted, thanks.

However, I would like to know how to correctly apply the third and fourth parameters of `belongsToMany()`...

Comment: The third parameter on a `belongsToMany()` is the current models *foreign key*, meaning *How is the current models database table linked to the pivot table?*. So in the `tags()` relation shown above, since we're calling it on the `Object` model, and its table is `objects`, the foreign key is `object_id`. The fourth parameter is the *other key*, meaning *What is the other key of the **related model** on the specified pivot table?*. I hope I'm making sense here, but if not, let me know and I'll try to help the best I can :).